# SharePoint site column now appearing in all libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column

I have an instance of SharePoint online.  After creating a number of similar document libraries, I eventually created a site column, to save some time, and to keep data consistent.

I have a Site column called "Year" that is a multiple choice field with choices "2015-2016,2016-2017, 2017-2018, 2018-2019,etc".

Recently I have noticed, that the Year field is now appearing in all the libraries, whether I have put it there or not.  What's more troubling, is for the libraries that existed before I created the site column, there are now 2 columns with exactly the same name.

- Is this normal for site columns?
- If I delete the site column, and there are document libraries that are actually using that field, will they disappear?  (My guess is no, but it could impact things negatively if I were to do that, at the moment, I'm manually deleting the second column that is unused.)

Any enlightenment would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not normal. Instead of rushing to a fix, finding an explanation wouldn't hurt. I'd guess the site column was made to be a default column for some core content type ("Item" or such which is a parent to many). Situations like these are quite nasty. Meanwhile you hopefully have your playground site where you could mimic the situation by adding a site column for your site content type and use the site content type in a couple of locations with mockup content, and see how removing the site column affects.

Comment: Thank you Moe.  You mention "site column was made to be a default column for some core content type".  I haven't found a setting for that, but that does seem to be what is occurring.  Do you have any insight as to where I might look for this default setting?

Comment: Have a look at any of your library where this Year-column appears, from the library's settings see what content type is being used in the library (allow site content type changes from advanced settings if the content type isn't already visible), go to the content type's settings and look for it and for each of its parents where does the site column Year show up. It should narrow you to a site content type which could be using the site column. I'm afraid I can't detail this further as I don't have an access to any SP currently.

Comment: You found the initial cause to your issue and was able to fix it? Great if so! I can try to format these comments into an answer to provide the solution's visibility.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: It's not normal.

For the second: Instead of rushing to a fix, finding an explanation to your issue would be a more preferable approach. I would guess the site column was made to be a default column for some of the SP's core content types ("Item" or such which is a parent to many). Situations like these are generally quite nasty.

Have a look at any of your library where this Year-column appears, and then from the library's settings see what content type is being used in the library (allow site content type changes from advanced settings if the content type isn't already visible). Go to the content type's settings and look for it and for each of its parents where does the site column Year show up. It should narrow you to a site content type which could be using the site column.

Generally to see if removal of something causes unexpected behavior, it's better to be executed first in a safe environment. One could attempt to mimic the situation in your playground by adding a site column for your site content type and use the site content type in a couple of locations with mock-up content, and see how removing the site column affects.